# How can I get T-SQL to show a value that doesn't occurs more than once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm sorry, I'm newbie using T-SQL AND I would like to know how can i get value that doesn't occurs more than once. I already tried this but it didn't work.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE PmtType  NOT IN ('VISA','DISC','FUNDING','DEALER CHECK','MC'
                       ,'AMEX','BONUS POOL','DLR CK - NET30'
                       ,'WIRE','MO','EXCHANGE','ONLINE','NULL')  
   AND OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-03-01 00:00:00' 
                          and '2015-03-01 00:00:00' 
   AND CompanyId  IN ('1311','8390','8394','8396','8397','8399','3966',
                     '8407','8408','8315','8411','8413','8414','8416'
                     ,'8419','4850','8426','8428','8429','8430')
```

What I'm trying to get is this. Companies that receive Free Demos. Which the PmtType would be free, but never purchased a product.

If the customer never purchase a product the customer Id shouldn't appear in the

```
PmtType IN ('VISA','DISC','FUNDING','DEALER CHECK'
            ,'MC' ,'AMEX','BONUS POOL','DLR CK - NET30'
            ,'WIRE','MO','EXCHANGE','ONLINE','NULL')
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve.  Which value are you trying to eliminate duplicates of?  Could you provide some sample input and expected output that would highlight the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What I'm trying to get is this. Companies that receive Free Demos. Which the PmtType  would be free, but never purchased a product. So if the customer never purchase a product the customer Id shouldn't appear in the PmtType ('VISA','DISC','FUNDING','DEALER CHECK','MC' ,'AMEX','BONUS POOL','DLR CK - NET30'
                       ,'WIRE','MO','EXCHANGE','ONLINE','NULL')

Comment: @AlLee That changes the question significantly, see answer edit below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i read the question correctly you want to know which IDs have only 1 order, this will do it.  I used generic field name as you didnt specify what "value" you want to find...

EDIT: added the `NOT EXISTS` clause after OP Comment, you may no longer need the group by, that is up to you...

```sql
SELECT CompanyId --add fields here as needed.
     ,Count(*) [Occurences]
FROM Orders o
WHERE PmtType = 'FREE'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT CompanyId 
                FROM Orders io 
                WHERE o.CompanyId = io.CompanyId 
                    AND PmtType <> 'FREE' )
GROUP BY CompanyId --add fields here as needed.
HAVING Count(*) = 1  --leave this out to see how many free demos each company got.
```